# vue nuxt qrcode reader installation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, qr-code

I'm having a Nuxt.js project where I try to use the [qrcode-scanner library](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader) 
I fallow the steps to register globaly.

I made a js file in plugins folder and add the fallowing code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueQrcodeReader from "vue-qrcode-reader";

Vue.use(VueQrcodeReader);
```

It looks pretty straight forward, but my app crashes and never loads. Anyone experienced this problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i test your code and it works for me by the way i explain my steps for you, maybe you forget one step:

1. install package with `npm install vue-qrcode-reader`
2. make file named `qr.js` in my `plugin` folder
3. then put this code on it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueQrcodeReader from 'vue-qrcode-reader'

Vue.use(VueQrcodeReader)
```

4. add plugin to my `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
  plugins: ['~/plugins/qr']
```

NOTE:`qr` is the name of my file(qr.js)

5. use the plugin in my vue page with adding following code in it's place:

```
<qrcode-stream></qrcode-stream>
<qrcode-drop-zone></qrcode-drop-zone>
<qrcode-capture></qrcode-capture>
```

Comment: thank you, i forgot to post my solution. For me it was a little bit different since i had SSR.

You can read more here https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader/issues/159

`plugins: [{ src: '@/plugins/QReader.js', mode: 'client' }],`